Arduino ESP32C3 example project RMakerSwitch sketch too big
Hardware: ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1
IDE: Arduino IDE
OS: Windows 11
Issue: When I run ESP32C3 Dev Module example project RMakerSwitch and RMakerCustom, it shows the following error. It's an example code, why it has this issue? Do I need to change flash size, or partition scheme, or something else?
Sketch uses 2040220 bytes (155%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 60236 bytes (18%) of dynamic memory, leaving 267444 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
Sketch too big; see https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360013825179 for tips on reducing it.
text section exceeds available space in board
Compilation error: text section exceeds available space in board


The message gives a link for help. Did you read it?

as you can see the selected partitions scheme has 1.2 MB for app. and your app is larger

Thank you very much for support, remkey and Juraj. The error msg says: sketch is too large. ESP32-C3-DevKitM-1 has 4 MB flash. So I changed the Partition scheme to "RainMaker 4MB no OTA", and it works. However, it will disable the OTA function. How to solve it? Thanks you!
